# Custom Action not being fired

Tags: deployment, custom-action

Recently, I was assigned the task to create a deployment package for an application which btw, I'm totally new at. So far, so good.. Now there is a requirement to extract files from a zip file which will be bundled with the setup file. So, I had to write custom actions in the 'Commit' section of the Installer class. I added the Installer class in a new project of type 'Class Library' under the same solution.  I wrote the code after 'base.Commit(savedState)'.

I tried showing MessageBox at the event entry point, used Debugger.Launch(), Debugger.Break() but somehow, no matter what I do, it seems that the custom action is not willing to be hit at all and the application just installs itself. I searched a lot of sites and blogs but no help so far.

I've assigned my installer class (SampleApp.exe, in my case) to all the Custom Action's modes (Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall) in the Deployment project. Any help.

**P.S. I'm using a Visual Studio 2010 setup project.**

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be trying a class library Dll, not an executable (which is typically for something like a service).

You don't need it all the nodes if all you're doing is calling at Commit. And why Commit? Install is just the same in most cases.

If you're not seeing a MessageBox then probably your CA isn't being called, and that may because it's not a class library. Note that your CA is not running in the interactive user context - it's being called from an msiexec process running with the system account, so you must be very explicit about (say) the path to the zip file, and any user profile folders will probably fail because the system account doesn't really have them.

Comment: I'm using a Class library dll since the installer class is in a project of type Class Library'. I've it in the "ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug" folder containing the 'ClassLibrary1.dll' file. Regarding the SampleApp, I only have the .exe file, there is no .dll file. Its a windows form application.
I'm using Commit because I just want to make sure that the custom action runs because no custom action will run before the Install event... A VS setup project, I'm using!

Comment: Do I need to add 'ClassLibrary1.dll' to the Custom Action's Commit mode?
'ClassLibrary1.dll' is a project of type 'Class Library'...

Comment: You need a class library Dll   because you need to be calling Install methods in a class library Dll not an exe. Yes, add that Dll to the Install node. This https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx and http://devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. your advice worked indeed :) What I was doing was adding the ClassLibrary1.dll to the Install nodes which was not working and throwing me a 1001 error. Instead, I added the "Primary output from ClassLibrary1 (Active)"... And bingo! Thanks, once again!! :)

Answer (score 0):

What files are these and where are they going on disk? If they are **user profile files** you can install the zip files to a per machine location and then **have the application itself unzip the files** to the desired location on **first launch**. Unzipping from within your setup is not good practice - it is error prone and bad design.

Using the application allows **proper exception handling** and **interactivity** (the user can be informed if something goes wrong). Set some registry flags in HKCU when you have completed the unzipping so it doesn't happen more than once, and perform the unzip once per user.

Comment: They aren't user profile files, just a mongoDB zip file. They will be extracted to the same location where the main application will be installed. How can I have my application unzip the files? I'm using a VS setup project.